# System.IO.IOException: "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

Tags: csvhelper

Sorry for mistakes. I use Google translate.
Can you please tell me how can I asynchronously write data to a file. When I try to do this I get an exception: System.IO.IOException: "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

```
public async Task WriteAsync(ToyInformation toy)
        {
            Encoding encoding = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode;
            if (!File.Exists(_path))
            {
                File.Create(_path);
            }
            
            //lock (_locker)
            //{
                using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(_path, true, encoding))
                {
                    
                    using CsvWriter csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, _csvConfiguration);
                    await csvWriter.NextRecordAsync();
                    csvWriter.WriteRecord(toy);
                    id++;
                    Console.WriteLine(new StringBuilder("Запись произведена ").Append(id).Append(" ").Append(DateTime.Now));
                }
            //}
            
        }
```

Tried using a 'lock', but it doesn't help at all.

```
public async Task ParsePageAsync(IHtmlDocument document, int numberPage)
        {
            var items = _parser.Parse?.Invoke(document);

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                var toyUrl = item.GetAttribute("href");
                var toyDocument = await _toyDocumentCreator.GetDocumentForParseAsync(toyUrl);

                var toy = GetToyInformation(toyDocument);
                toy.ProductUrl = toyUrl;
                toy.PageNumber = numberPage;
                await _customCsvWriter.WriteAsync(toy);
            }

        }
```

The above method is called via 'Parallel.For'. Tell me, is there a way to control writing to a file so that only one thread can access it while writing text to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are locking the file with `File.Create(_path)`. You don't need to create the file ahead of time and can remove this code.

```cs
if (!File.Exists(_path))
{
   File.Create(_path);
}
```

If it is possible that the directory does not exist, you could create the directory.

```cs
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(_path);

Directory.CreateDirectory(fileInfo.Directory.FullName);
```

Now your `lock` should work.

Comment: Thank you. I removed the part of the code you mentioned. She really isn't needed. I used a mutex instead of a lock. I noticed that everything is in order, when the file is already created, the threads queue up. And if the file does not exist, then it provokes an exception.

```
if (!File.Exists(_path))
{
   File.Create(_path);
}
```